# Remove tab from grep output

Tags: tabs

I have a command that looks for where an IP address has been on a particular day.  It looks like this:

zcat /nsm/bro/logs/[DATE]/http_eth1.* | bro-cut -D "%G-%m-%d %R:%S" ts id.orig_h host uri | grep [IP_Address]

It works great except for one thing.  The output looks like this:

2013-01-16 23:38:26     [IP_Address]   safebrowsing-cache.google.com   /safebrowsing/rd/ChFnb29nLXBoaXNoLXNoYXZhchAAGIX_DyCY_w8yB4X_AwD__w8

There is a tab between "safebrowsing-cache.google.com" and "/safebrowsing/rd/ChFnb29nLXBoaXNoLXNoYXZhchAAGIX_DyCY_w8yB4X_AwD__w8".  I would like to remove that specific tab only.  Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

use `awk`

Example: `echo -n 'first\tsecond\tthird\tfourth\n' | awk '{ print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3$4 }'`
outputs `first\tsecond\tthirdfourth` -- the tab between "third" and "fourth" has been removed.